# How can I lint cshtml files with vscode?

Tags: razor, visual-studio-code, lint

As a frontend developer, sometimes I have to edit projects that are written in .net mvc and I have to edit cshtml files.

I'm using htmlhint extension for vscode (which is perfect to prevent syntax errors for static htmls) but it isn't recognize cshtml (razor) files.

Is there any way to do this without using visual studio?

I just want to see error if I write code like this

```
<div> test </a>
```